# Run the macro even if the last 3 letters is renamed

Tags: excel, rename

Good day,

May I ask if it is possible to run the macro even if some letters or characters on the title of the workbook I am working with is renamed?

this is the code I am working with:

```
Sub WBS()
    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

    Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Total cost.xlsm").Worksheets(3).Range("A3:A300")
    Set targetColumn = Workbooks("backing sheet (Jan).xlsm").Worksheets(2).Range("D6:D300")

    sourceColumn.Copy
    targetColumn.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                          SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Call Resource_Name
End Sub
```

what I really want to do is run the macro even if the name of the workbook is changed. as you can see the value I am copying is pasted on **"backing sheet (Jan).xlsm"** I want to change the name to **"backing sheet (Feb).xlsm"** and I know it wont run because the target workbook does not exist technically.

is there any possible way to deal with this?

Comment: why cant you just change the vba code to point to the new name?

Comment: thanks for the comment nick, what I am really thinking is , I want it to be a bit dynamic. because every month I am changing the backing sheet name.

Comment: So you don't want to have to change anything each month?

Comment: what I want to change is the month only(e.g. Backing sheet (Jan) to Backing sheet (Feb) ), and the program will still run because of the title Backing sheet regardless of what will be the next text or word.

Comment: What I'm saying is you don't want to change the program?

Comment: yes mate, is there any code for that? like Set targetColumn = Workbooks("backing sheet ("TXT").xlsm").Worksheets(2).Range("D6:D300")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a named range in your program with the date abbreviation - say called `monthAbbr`.  Edit this every month.  Then, change the VBA code to

```
Sub WBS()

    Dim monthAbbr As String
    monthAbbr = Range("monthAbbr").Value

    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

    Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Total cost.xlsm").Worksheets(3).Range("A3:A300")
    Set targetColumn = Workbooks("backing sheet " & monthAbbr & ".xlsm").Worksheets(2).Range("D6:D300")

    sourceColumn.Copy
    targetColumn.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                          SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Call Resource_Name
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the answer nick, however it gives me a Compile error: "User -defined type not define" it gives me error on the Dim monthabbr as text

Comment: hello again nick, actually I tried it to change As string but it gives me an error on giving it value. "monthabbr = range("monthabbr").value

Answer (score -1):

I did it :). why did I make this code complicated.
incase others want to know the answer please see the code below.

```
Sub WBS()

Dim monthAbbr As String
monthAbbr = Range("monthAbbr").Value

Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Total cost.xlsm").Worksheets(3).Range("A3:A300")
Set targetColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("D6:D300")

sourceColumn.Copy
targetColumn.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                      SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Call Resource_Name
```

I forgot that there is a ThisWorkbook code. I can even change the whole name of my file :)